# How to wait for service call to finish calling and once its is success call the same service again in Angular 2

Tags: angular, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

Hi I have an angular project with a file upload component.Whenever a user drags/select a file a service call is triggering to upload that file.If there is any error then i show a popup with that error. The problem am facing is if user selects or drags 5 files i have 5 different pop ups. So how can i call the 1st service then waits for the completion and upload next file? Or any better suggestion guys?

- On Select or Drag service call

> ```
> getFile(file) {
>          file.map(obj => {
>              if (!_.find(this.fileList, { fileName: obj.name })) {
>                  this.fileList.push(obj);
>                  obj.extension = obj.name.substring(obj.name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
>                  if (_.includes(this.allowedExtensions, obj.extension)) {
>                      this.UploadFile(this.fileList).subscribe((data: any) => {
>                          if (data) {
>                              if (data.response) {
>                                  this.fileShowList.push(data.response);
>                              }
>                          }      
>                     }, (error) => {
>                         this.mdDialog.open(ErrorDialogComponent, {
>                             'data': {
>                                 'type': 'error',
>                                 'title': `error `,
>                                 'content': `Error`
>                             },
>                             'disableClose': true
>                         });
>                     });
>                 } else {
>                     let infoDialog = this.mdDialog.open(ErrorDialogComponent, {
>                         'data': {
>                             'type': 'error',
>                             'title': `File type not allowed`,
>                             'content': `File type not allowed`
>                         },
>                         'disableClose': true
>                     });
>                 }
>             } else {
>                 let infoDialog = this.mdDialog.open(ErrorDialogComponent, {
>                     'data': {
>                         'type': 'error',
>                         'title': `You cant upload files with same name`,
>                         'content': `You cant upload files with same name`
>                     },
>                     'disableClose': true
>                 });
>             }
>         });
>     }
> ```

- Upload service call:

  `UploadFile(files: Array<any>) {
          let _self = this;
          const dataUrl =`/Backend/uploadFile`;
          let fileObjectArray: Array<any> = [];
          return Observable.fromPromise(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              let formData: any = new FormData(),
                  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
              formData.append('applicationId', 's');
              formData.append('token', 'ss');
              formData.append('filename', files[0], files[0].name);
              xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                  if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                      if (xhr.status === 200) {
                          _self.btnText = 'Upload files';
                          _self.uploadFile = false;
                          let responseObj = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
                          if (responseObj.status.code) {
                              let dialogRef = _self.mdDialog.open(ErrorDialogComponent, {
                                  'data':
                                  {
                                      'type': 'error',
                                      'title': responseObj.status.message,
                                  }
                              });
                              dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((close: boolean) => {
                                  if (close) {
                                      _self.ngOnInit();
                                  }
                              });
                          } else {
                              resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
                          }
                          resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
                      } else {
                          reject(xhr.response);
                      }
                  }
              };
              xhr.open('POST', dataUrl, true);
              xhr.send(formData);
          }));
      }`

Comment: You can use the rxjs operator finalize(). example = `this.paymentMessage$ = this.creditCardService.payStorage(equipPayment).pipe(
      finalize(() => {
        //Call your service again
      })
    );`

Comment: you gotta import it from import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';

Comment: Hi @PatricioVargas, can show that as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rxjs operator finalize(). 
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/finalize.html

**Call method when observable completes or errors.**

example:

```
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators'; 
.
.
.
this.paymentMessage$ = this.creditCardService.payStorage(equipPayment)
.pipe( 
  finalize(() => { 
     //Call your service again 
  }) 
);
```

Comment: Yes Patricio, but will it call my service 2 times even if i upload one file?